# Photos trim tool reducing the clip's fps

Tags: windows-10

Whenever I use the Photos app on Windows 10 to trim a .mp4 video, it seems that the output trimmed video is of a substantially lower framerate. Is there any workaround or fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have much control over the Photos app, nor are you the only one to complain
about its generated video quality.
The only solution is to use a better software.

If trimming is the only operation, you may use for example
[Lossless Cut](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut),
advertising itself as "The swiss army knife of lossless video/audio editing".

Or see the article
[Best Free Video Cutter and Joiner](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-software-cut-split-or-merge-video-files.htm).

Comment: lossless cut works perfectly for my needs, thanks! i also saw it export a csv file with a timestamp on it or something, it's probably safe to delete that, right?

Comment: The documentation mentions "View segment details, export/import cut segments as CSV", so probably this is a summary of the operation you did. It can be deleted, and you could check if some preference exists for turning it off.

Comment: Just wanted to come back to this and say thank you again. I've been using this tool heavily ever since, and I've put so many people on to this tool. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

FIX: INSTEAD OF SELECT "TRIM", SELECT "SLOW MOTION", TRIM THE VIDEO IN THAT OPTION AND MOVE THE SLOW MOTTION EFFECT TO 0 in the top, save and ready. 60fps or whatever you have.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).